# Google Maps // "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, advanced-custom-fields

I'm implementing Google Maps onto a Wordpress website that will allow the user to add locations to the Map using Advanced Custom Fields. The map loads in great, but the icons/markers don't seem to be loading in right. I get an error that reads, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined" in the Chrome Developer Tool Inspector.

Do I need to add anything? I'm new to Google Maps and firing it off and what not. Here's what I'm using:

```
<?php // Index template
get_header(); ?>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div class="twelve column">
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="intro">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <hr>
            </div>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <header class="clearfix"></header>
                        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
                                <?php
                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=locations'); // exclude category 9
                                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                                    <?php if(get_field('link')): ?>
                                      <div>
                                        <?php while(has_sub_field('link')): ?>
                                          <div>
                                              <p><?php the_sub_field('url'); ?></p>
                                          </div>
                                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                                      </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <?php
                                function get_single_term($post_id, $taxonomy)
                                {
                                  $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
                                  if(!is_wp_error($terms)) {
                                    return '<a href="'.get_term_link($terms[0]->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.$terms[0]->name.'</a>';
                                  }
                                }

                                $i = 0;

                                // For creating multiple, customized loops.
                                // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
                                    $custom_query = new WP_Query('post_type=location&posts_per_page=-1');
                                    while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();

                                      $title = get_the_title(); // Location title
                                      $map   = get_field('location'); // ACF location contains address and coordinates
                                      $terms = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'distributors', '', ' & ' )); // Get distributor terms and rm links
                                      $info  = '<strong>' . $terms . '</strong><br>' . $title; // Info window content
                                      $url = the_sub_field('url');
                                      if(get_field('link')){
                                        echo '<ul>';
                                        while(has_sub_field('link')){
                                          $info .= '<li><a href="http://'.get_sub_field('url').'">'.get_sub_field('url').'</a></li>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                      }
                                      $location[$i][0] = $title; // Store the post title
                                      $location[$i][1] = $map['coordinates']; // Store the ACF coordinates
                                      $location[$i][2] = json_encode($info); // Store info window content
                                      $location[$i][3] = strip_tags( get_single_term( $post->ID, 'distributor' )); // Get first term for marker icon

                                      $i ++;
                                    endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

                                <script>
                                $(function initialize() {

                                  // Center map on our main location
                                  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.583013,-93.63701500000002); 

                                  var map;
                                  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                                  // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling
                                  // Create an array of styles.
                                  var styles = [
                                    {
                                      stylers: [
                                        { saturation: -99.9 }
                                      ]
                                    }
                                  ];

                                  // Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
                                  // as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
                                  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: 'exile'});

                                  // Create a map object, and include the MapTypeId to add
                                  // to the map type control.
                                  var mapOptions = {
                                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
                                    center: myLatLng,
                                    zoom: 8,
                                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                                    scrollwheel: true,
                                    draggable: true
                                  };
                                  // Display a map on the page
                                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapOptions);
                                  map.setTilt(45);

                                  //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
                                  map.mapTypes.set('exile', styledMap);
                                  map.setMapTypeId('exile');                                

                                // Marker icons
                                  typeObject = {
                                    "Home" : {
                                      "icon" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/target.png', new google.maps.Size(28,28), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(36,14)),
                                      "shadow" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', new google.maps.Size(40,34))
                                    },
                                    "Others" : {
                                      "icon" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/beer-mug.png', new google.maps.Size(18,26), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(9,26)),
                                      "shadow" : new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png', new google.maps.Size(40,34))
                                    }
                                  }

                                  // http://wrightshq.com/playground/placing-multiple-markers-on-a-google-map-using-api-3/
                                  // Multiple Markers
                                  var markers = [
                                    ["Exile Brewing Co", 41.583013,-93.63701500000002,"Others"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)){
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '["' . $location[$key][0] . '",' . $location[$key][1] . ',"' . $location[$key][3] . '"]';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];

                                  // Info Window Content
                                  var infoWindowContent = [
                                    ["<strong>Exile Brewing Co.</strong><br>1514 Walnut Street, Des Moines"],
                                    <?php
                                    if (count($location)>0) {
                                      foreach ($location as $key => $value){
                                        if ($key < (count($location)-1)) {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . '], ' . "\n";
                                        } else {
                                          echo '[' . $location[$key][2] . ']';
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                  ];

                                  // Display multiple markers on a map
                                  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

                                  // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map
                                  for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
                                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]); // ACF coordinates
                                    var icon = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['icon'];
                                    var shadow = typeObject[markers[i][3]]['shadow'];
                                    bounds.extend(position);
                                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                      position: position,
                                      map: map,
                                      title: markers[i][0],
                                      icon: icon,
                                      shadow: shadow
                                    });

                                    // Allow each marker to have an info window
                                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                                      return function() {
                                        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                      }
                                    })(marker, i));

                                    // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                                    //map.fitBounds(bounds);
                                  }

                                  // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
                                  var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                                    this.setZoom(15);
                                    google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
                                  });

                                });
                                </script>
                              <div id="panel">
                              Search within 
                              <input id="address" type="textbox" value="10"> 
                               miles of zipcode
                              <input id="address" type="textbox" value="50266">
                              <input class = "button" type="button" value="Find it!" onclick="codeAddress()">
                            </div>

                <footer class="clearfix"></footer>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here's the link to the page I'm working on too:
http://exilebrewing.com/locations/

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `typeObject` contains 2 properties (`Home` and `Others`)

Your script will fail when the 4th item of a item in `markers` doesn't match 1 of these property-names.

This currently happens:

```
var markers = [
 ["Exile Brewing Co", 41.583013,-93.63701500000002,"Others"],
 ["Exile Brewing Co",41.583013,-93.63701500000002,""]
//this must be either Home or Others--------------^                              
];
```

You may either fix `markers` or use a fallback when the property can't be found:

```
for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
 var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]); 

 //use typeObject.Others when property can't be found
 var icon   = (typeObject[markers[i][3]]||typeObject.Others).icon;
 var shadow = (typeObject[markers[i][3]]||typeObject.Others).shadow;

//continue with your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I fixed the markers with the updates you provided, but I'm still getting the same error... :/

Comment: I also noticed that the .pngs I have associated with the icons are coming in as broken.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, use the modified code. The PNG's are not broken, they are missing.

Comment: Looks like that passed through! Great! But now I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var" towards the bottom of that code between these two lines: 
     'var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                                    this.setZoom(15);'